# Calling Group on an Array in Ruby/Rails

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

I have a fairly complex app in rails 4.0.x so I won't go into the logic too deeply but will explain what I'm having a problem with.

I have a warrant model where I wrote a class method to replace a simple scope like this.  It uses casing to replace warrant types and show me all warrants that are considered active and open.

```
  def self.active_and_open
    find_by_sql("
    select id, case warn_type when 'FT' then 'AW' when 'WI' then 'AW' when 'VP' then 'AW' when 'AW' then 'AW' when 'CP' then 'CP' when 'CW' then 'CP' end as warn_type, warn_date_issued, warn_status, warnv_citation_no, warnv_viol_no warnv_name_code, created_at, updated_at, last_seen_at, citation_id, person_id,warn_docket_no, warn_closed_date, warn_rid, violation_id, total, rank, changed_by, collection_fee, collection_amount, exclude_from_collection, open_coll_at from warrants WHERE (warn_closed_date is null and warn_status = '')
     ")
  end
```

I then have a method in my person model (Person has many warrants association) with a method to call the warrants on the Person object show active_and_open warrants and group by `warn_type` and `warn_closed_date`

```
   def open_warrant_types
    warrants.active_and_open.group(:warn_type, :warn_closed_date).count(:warn_type)
  end
```

Then in my person helper I call that method like this and try to group the warrants by first translating them based on warrant type then showing a count ie `1 bondable 1 non bondable` `name` is the person object I'm passing

```
 def open_warrants_types_and_counts(name)
 ( name.open_warrant_types2.collect{ |wt| "#{wt.last}  #{translate_warrant_type(Warrant::WARRANT_TYPE[(wt.first.kind_of?(Array) ? wt.first.first : wt.first)])}" }.join(', ') )
  end
```

The problem I'm having is that this class method `self.active_and_open` creates an array and in the `open_warrant_types` I get `undefined method group for array`.  My old scope or active_and_open returned a hash and here's the scope below:

```
scope :active_and_open, -> {where("warn_closed_date is null and warn_status <> 'I'")}
```

This hash when passed to the .group method in `open_warrant_types` worked fine, but I'm not sure how I can have this same functionality with an array.  I've never used the `.group` method only `.group_by` and the API docs don't tell me what I need to know on how to call `.group` on an array.

I realize this code is probably very complicated so I'm open to refactoring and suggestions, but for now I'm just trying to figure out how to call `.group` on the array OR convert the array into a hash with persisted `k,v` so I can use the existing methods in place.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do s.th. like `Warrant.select('warrants.*, case warn_type when 'FT' then 'AW' when 'WI' then 'AW' when 'VP' then 'AW' when 'AW' then 'AW' when 'CP' then 'CP' when 'CW' then 'CP' end as warn_type')` then you get an ActiveRecord expression you can call the usual suspects on.

But I strongly reccommend to keep native SQL out of your app as much as possible and do the translation your doing in SQL in the app.

i.e. make a hash to translate your warn_types:

```
WT_HASH = {
'FT' => 'AW',
'VP' then 'AW',
..
}
```

to create a method

```
class Warrant

def translated_warn_type
  WT_HASH[self.warn_type]
end
..
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  But the select would be on the warrant class no?  Since active_and_open is a scope/method on Warrant, not person.  Can you give me an example of how I would do this?

Comment: I already have something in place to do the warrant translation using a hash.  The code you provided didn't work unfortunately.  Can I provide you with a specific query and you and I can work on translating that into AR?